# How to get List of object on Login and use till logout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What i am doing is :
**1. I am fetching the Roles of Uses on Layout page.**

```
 @{
        List<string> UserRole = new List<string>();
        if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){
            UserRole = DocRevGen.Class.Common.Roles(User.Identity.Name);   
        }

    }
```

**2. Using this UserRole like.**

```
@{
                        if (UserRole.Contains("Admin") || UserRole.Contains("User"))
                        {
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview</a></li>    
                        }
                    }
```

But problem is that `UserRole` is called every time on page load.
**I want to fill `UserRole` one time while login and use the `UserRole` till the logout.**

Is there any solution for this.
I just want a hint. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can save this in session variable:

```
Session["roles"] = UserRole;
```

to get it from session:

```
var roles = (List<string>)Session["roles"];
```

But it is not so good idea, cause if some of user roles will be removed, it will be applied only when user logout or session timeouted.

Comment: If roles changed by administrator, we cannot update session of current user. Maximum session can be droped

Answer (score 0):

You can use database and store the info there. Or you could also use global variables then just access the info you need.